# Running of a Thread at a given time

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

My question is somewhat related to Caching, Suppose some threads are accessing my information every 2 sec, and it is getting updated in the database after every 3 minutes, So it is better for me to make a hashmap of the information that is fetched by those threads and update it after every 3 minutes and all threads are getting the data from hashmap. My question is "How will I make sure that exactly after 3 minutes my hashmap will be updated by some other thread, and all the time thread should get the latest information".

Comment: You specify exactly 3 minutes and having the latest information. This will be hard to accomplish, imagine that you have a thread that checks after exactly 3minutes, but the input is a bit slow, say it takes 3 minutes and 1 microsecond. You will now read old data. Normally with caching you accept some amount of "staleness". There are ways to have the database notify your program about changes but from your description it sounds unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Roger So can we say that using caching we can't remove staleness in data, we have some tools in market like memcache so by using them as well can't we remove this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cache with fixed expiry time in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340578/cache-with-fixed-expiry-time-in-java)

Comment: I would assume that 3 minutes is arbitrarily chosen. If it polls every 3 minutes and one milli-second is your program going to behave incorrectly?  I suspect not.  In short, don't make the program more complicated than it needs to be by adding requirements which aren't needed. I suggest you try removing requirements like "exactly" until the program wouldn't be considered to be working an implement that. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logic like this to access the data:

1) Acquire the lock that protects the data.

2) Check when was the last time the data was updated.

3) If the data is current enough, copy the data you need, release the lock, and **stop**.

4) Update the data.

5) Update the timestamp that is checked in step 2.

6) Copy out the new data.

7) Release the lock.

Alternatively, you can have a dedicated thread just to update the data as needed.

Comment: Are you sure that every time when my thread fetches data from the hashMap or some collection, the data will be in sync with Database, I mean the fresh data always.

Comment: If you need fresh data always, don't cache.

Comment: But if I know the specific timing that after 5 minutes my data get updated in database. So is there any problem in caching and getting the latest data. By fresh data I mean data same as in the DB

Comment: If you can tell if the data is stale, then check. If it's stale update it. If you can't tell if the data is stale and you need the latest data, don't cache.